# Powershell - pass PSCredential object to new command window

Tags: powershell, command-line, arguments

I have a powershell script which calls Get-Credential. The entered credentials are to be used against multiple servers later on in the script and child scripts.

The code looks something like:

```
$credentials = get-credential
CMD /c start powershell.exe -noexit -File subscript.ps1 $credentials
```

The issue is inside subscript.ps1 I have this code just to see whats coming in:

```
$args.length
$args[0]
```

which gives me
1
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential

As you can see it does not pass the actual object returned by the Get-Credential call.

My guess is this is happening because we are calling the script by a new command window. We need to open a new command window as we need to open 4 different subscript.ps1 (with different parameters for parallel processing).

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PowerShell V3, use below syntax to start async background task

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($cred) . C:\test.ps1 $cred} -ArgumentList $cred
wait-job $job 
receive-job $job
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears you're already starting your process from within PowerShell use the `Start-Process` cmdlet which accepts `-Credential`.